# Cross compiling for Openwrt giving cannot convert error

Tags: cross-compiling, openwrt

I tried to build click modular router for OpenWrt 14.04 device, with MIPS32 architecture. (With the help of instructions here : https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/devel/crosscompile). I have successfully built toolchain for OpenWRT.

Here is end of failure log : (I can put whole logs if it is necessary)

```
.
.
.
      CXX elementmap.cc
      CXX ../../lib/userutils.cc
      CXX ../../lib/md5.cc
      CXX toolutils.cc
      CC ../../lib/clp.c
      AR libclicktool.a
      RANLIB libclicktool.a
      BUILDCXX ../../lib/string.cc
      BUILDCXX ../../lib/straccum.cc
      BUILDCXX ../../lib/glue.cc
      BUILDCXX ../../lib/bitvector.cc
      BUILDCXX ../../lib/hashallocator.cc
      BUILDCXX ../../lib/ipaddress.cc
      BUILDCXX ../../lib/etheraddress.cc
      BUILDCXX ../../lib/timestamp.cc
      BUILDCXX ../../lib/error.cc
    ../../lib/error.cc: In static member function ‘static String ErrorHandler::vxformat(int, const char*, __va_list_tag*)’:
    ../../lib/error.cc:724:52: error: cannot convert ‘__va_list_tag**’ to ‘__va_list_tag (*)[1]’ in argument passing
           strstore = item->hook(flags, VA_LIST_REF(val));
                                                        ^
    make[2]: *** [error.bo] Error 1
    make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/kerematam/sodev/wi5/cross-click/click/tools/lib'
    make[1]: *** [lib] Error 2
    make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/kerematam/sodev/wi5/cross-click/click/tools'
    make: *** [tools] Error 2
```

Here is what I run to for build :

```
export CC=/home/kerematam/openwrt/trunk/staging_dir/toolchain-mips_34kc_gcc-4.8-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/bin/mips-openwrt-linux-gcc

export CXX=/home/kerematam/openwrt/trunk/staging_dir/toolchain-mips_34kc_gcc-4.8-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/bin/mips-openwrt-linux-g++

export PATH=/home/kerematam/openwrt/trunk/staging_dir/toolchain-mips_34kc_gcc-4.8-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/:$PATH

export STAGING_DIR=/home/kerematam/openwrt/trunk/staging_dir/toolchain-mips_34kc_gcc-4.8-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/

./configure --host=mips-unknown-elf --build=x86_64-unkown-linux-gnu --prefix=/home/kerematam/openwrt/trunk/staging_dir/toolchain-mips_34kc_gcc-4.8-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/ --with-linux=/home/kerematam/openwrt/trunk/build_dir/toolchain-mips_34kc_gcc-4.8-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/linux/
```

I am not that experienced on cross compiling environment. I might be missing something. Any suggestion what might causing this?

Comment: It looks like this is an issue with your sources rather than cross compiling. Can you compile it for your host machine?

Comment: Yes, I have compiled it for my own PC.